# JQuery-js: submit() doesen't work if form contains a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I've noticed that js `submit()` isn't working if the form contains an input of "submit" type.

I would know if it's a known behaviour (I haven't find any documentation about that) or it can be a js issue.

Here [the Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmkt9f13/1/): try to remove the button inside and it works.

Comment: Ok the problem was the name "submit" of the input button.
Thanks to epascarello!

Comment: When you name the button submit, you override the submit() function on the form